# Mysql in eclipse indigo

Tags: mysql, eclipse, hibernate, eclipse-plugin

I Have run an Hibernate application, where it should create a table name `Userdet` and insert values for `username` & `userID`. But when i drag down the MySQL database Poo i cant find any table been created. But Hibernate application ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Are you possibly using "create-drop"? That causes schema to be dropped when SessionFactory is closed. If so, other options to create database via Hibernate are *create* and *update*.

Other common mistakes are connecting database other than assumed and/or checking wrong schema.